# Plot heatmap using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap

everyone. I have a problem when plotting heatmap with matplotlib.

***In short, the output heatmap figure is 'cropped'***. 
 ***I want to know WHY this problem arises and HOW to solve it***.

The problem is described as follows.

**1. Environment**

The program is created in below environment.

```
matplotlib==3.1.1
numpy==1.16.4
pandas==0.24.2
```

All libs are installed in conda virtual environment with pip.

**2. Reference code**

My code is created based on the official document: [Creating annotated heatmaps](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/images_contours_and_fields/image_annotated_heatmap.html)

**3. My code**

My code is given as follows:

```py
    import matplotlib as mpl
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import pandas as pd
    import numpy as np
    from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable


    def heatmap(data, ax, fmt='{x:d}'):
    """Plot a heatmap with matplotlib.

    Args:
        data (pandas.DataFrame): the matrix to be labeled.
        ax (matplotlib.axes.Axes): axes where the confusion matrix is drawn.
        fmt (string, optional): the format of the annotations inside the
            heatmap. This should either use the string format method,
            e.g. "{x:.2f}" or "{x:d}".

    Returns:
        ax (matplotlib.axes.Axes): axes where the confusion matrix is drawn.
    """

    if not isinstance(data, pd.DataFrame):
        raise TypeError('the input data should be a pandas DataFrame object')

    if data.shape[0] != data.shape[1]:
        raise ValueError('the data should be a square-matrix')

    im = ax.imshow(data.values, cmap='magma', interpolation='nearest')

    divider = make_axes_locatable(ax)
    cax = divider.append_axes('right', size='5%', pad=0.15)
    cbar = plt.colorbar(im, cax=cax,
                        ticks=mpl.ticker.MaxNLocator(nbins=6))
    cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=12)
    cbar.outline.set_visible(False)

    ax.set_xticks(list(np.arange(data.shape[1])))
    ax.set_yticks(list(np.arange(data.shape[0])))

    column_labels = list(data.columns.values.astype(str))
    ax.set_xticklabels(column_labels, fontsize=12, rotation='vertical')
    ax.set_yticklabels(column_labels, fontsize=12)

    for spine in ax.spines.values():
        spine.set_visible(False)

    valfmt = mpl.ticker.StrMethodFormatter(fmt)

    # Change the text's color depending on the background.
    text_colors = ['white', '0.15']
    threshold = 0.6

    for i in range(data.shape[0]):
        for j in range(data.shape[1]):
            use_dark = im.norm(data.iloc[i, j]) > threshold
            im.axes.text(
                j, i, valfmt(data.iloc[i, j], None),
                ha="center", va="center", fontsize=12,
                color=text_colors[int(use_dark)])

    return ax
```

**4. Input data**

The input data is a very simple pandas DataFrame.

```py
    confusion_df = pd.DataFrame([[89, 4], [5, 80]], index=['dog', 'cat'], columns=['dog', 'cat'])
```

**5. Output**

I create a confusion map figure as follows.

```py
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(4, 4))

    heatmap(confusion_df, ax=ax, fmt='{x:d}')

    ax.set_xlabel('Prediction', fontsize=16)
    ax.set_ylabel('Ground truth', fontsize=16)
    fig.tight_layout()

    fig.savefig('confusion_map.png')
    plt.show()
```

**6. Result**

The result is very strange, as I said bebore, the figure is 'cropped'.
[image: The 'cropped' heatmap]

**7. The result I want to get.**

The correct output should be a square like below. You can also check the results given in the reference document in 2.

[image: The figure I want to get]

**8. The methods I tried**

I tried the following methods but they do NOT work.

(a) compared my code with the code given in the reference document (see 2)

(b) set larger figure size, say `fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(6, 6))` in 3

(c) remove `fig.tight_layout()` in 5

**Thank you very much!**

Comment: The code works fine for me. No cropping. It must be something with your environment.

Comment: @Samik Hi, Samir! Thanks for your comment. Do you use the same versions of libs given in 1? And what is your OS?

Comment: I was using matplotlib 3.0.3. Looks like it is broken in 3.1.1

Comment: ＠Samik Yes, me too. It works well in matplotlib 3.0.1 but broken in 3.1.1.